# what is the use of Long.reverse(long ) method?

Tags: java, performance, api, reverse, long-integer

I found one method in Long class

`public static long reverse(long i) {..}`

What is the use of this method?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From an [DDJ article](http://www.ddj.com/architect/184404252):

> Why would you reverse the order of
>   bits in a 32-bit or 64-bit value? Bit
>   reversal can be useful in a variety of
>   contexts. It's useful in image
>   processing for flipping a
>   black-and-white image to create a
>   mirror image. To flip an image
>   horizontally, the pixels in a row of
>   the image must be placed in reverse
>   order. Fast 64-bit bit reversal can be
>   used in the process of reversing a row
>   of black-and-white pixels. Similarly,
>   64-bit bit reversal is useful for
>   rotating a black and white image 180
>   degrees.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently bit reversal is used in digital signal processing applications, as in the [Fast Fourier Transform](http://www.dspguide.com/ch12/2.htm). I won't pretend to understand *why* it works, but perhaps the linked-to page will be clear to you.

Comment: yes Jonathan. The linked page as well is very useful along with urs.

Answer (score 2):

You can use bit reversal to make it easier to work with masking operations.